# Bluetooth device identification & information during pairing

Tags: bluetooth

Let's say I'm creating a device that communicates with the computer using Bluetooth.
I'm at the point where pairing and exchanging data between the device and the computer works.

Is there anything in the BT specification that allows the BT device to "inform" the
computer where to get the drivers/software upon pairing?

1. Pair the device with the computer
2. Some information is passed to the computer (Windows for example)
3. The computer then informs the user where the required software can be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are talking about BLE or just classic bluetooth. In BLE you have a DIS profile (Device Information Service) which you can use to exchange device information.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I was talking about classic Bluetooth. I will look into what you mentioned, just not sure we can expect everyone to have BT4/LE.